# scrolling not working inside childview - swift(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, smooth-scrolling, childviewcontroller

[image]

I have added child view inside the containerview, containerview height will update as subview height changed.when Bzcardview display,it will hide containerview and when containerview display it will hide Bzcardview. Bazcardview and containerview both having same contraint.

```
func UpdateSubviewHeight()  {
    
    if  segmentHeaderView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
       
        self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant =  InformationTabView.InnerviewHeightContraint.constant + 50
    }
    else {
        self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant = self.BzcardView.view.height
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

private func addChildViewController(vc: UIViewController) {
  
    self.Containerview.addSubview(vc.view)
    if vc == FirstTabView
    {
        self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant =  InformationTabView.InnerviewHeightContraint.constant
    }
    else {
       self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant = vc.view.height
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       

    activateRequiredConstraints(for: vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
}

private func activateRequiredConstraints(for childView: UIView) {
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Containerview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Containerview.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Containerview.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Containerview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Containerview.heightAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

When tab changed it just perform hide and show action.

```
if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
        self.InformationTabView.view.isHidden = false
        self.ExposuresView.view.isHidden = true
        self.Bzcardview_.isHidden = true
        self.scrollview.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.Bzcardview_.isHidden = true
        self.Bzcardview_.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    {
        self.InformationTabView.view.isHidden = true
        self.Bzcardview_.isHidden = false
        self.Bzcardview_.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.ExposuresView.view.isHidden = true
        self.scrollview.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

Comment: Use debug Hierarchy to see scrollview and child view's property.

Comment: in hierarchy  I have print child view & container height changes and inside output values were updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        if self.Bzcardview_.isHidden{
            self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant = vc.view.height
            self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant = self.BzcardView.view.height
        }else{
            self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant =  InformationTabView.InnerviewHeightContraint.constant + 50
            self.containerviewHeighContraint.constant =  InformationTabView.InnerviewHeightContraint.constant
            
        }
    }
}
```